# Use module to complete a task to plot declination for over 100 years on given lattitude and longitude using cartopy and Hammer projection

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartopy

I have been assigned to make a plot of inclination in coordinates (33,-117) over the last 100 years using the module https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bqP4K-RUAo3HwgDyIcggJDQNHKaZzAi6

```html
import mkigrf

date=2023 
lon_0=0  0 longitude for the plot
Ds,Is,Bs,lons,lats=mkigrf.magMap(date,lon_0=lon_0)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Hammer(central_longitude=lon_0))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
lincr=1
levmax=Is.max()+lincr
levmin=round(Is.min()-lincr)
levels=np.arange(levmin,levmax,lincr)
m=ax.contourf(X,Y, Is, levels,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=cm.jet)
ax.contour(X,Y,Is,levels=np.arange(-80,90,10),transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),colors='black')
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
cbar=plt.colorbar(m,orientation='horizontal') # put on a color bar of intensities
plt.title('Inclination: '+str(date));
```

But this is just for one year. How to plot for 100 years. I used for loop as

```html
for data in np.arange(1920,2020):
```

and inserted above code inside for loop. But it takes forever to generate and each figure overlaps the previous one which i think is not right way to do it. Any help is appreciated.